# How can I automatically load nVidia X Server resolution settings on startup/login?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

First, yes I have searched far and wide for answers to this question.  There are many (far too many) answers, and thus far I have not found one which works.  I've tried various forms of "save the settings in some file under /etc", and "save the settings in some file under ~/.config".  I even tried some set of commands that were supposed to add the resolution I want to the believed-in resolutions.  It seems that over time the proper place to make changes to how the video settings get set moves.  Which I suppose is okay that things develop, but it would be nice if how/why/where was documented in some way.  But that's just my frustration talking.

I have a GTX 760, driving 2 monitors.  The primary monitor (right, if it matters) was recently upgraded to a nice 4k display.  While the 760 is capable of driving all these pixels, it's not...  happy.  I find life is much better if I turn down the resolution on the 4k to something like 2560x1440.  This is a resolution the display is perfectly happy to internally upscale, and the video card believes is a perfectly valid (if scaled) resolution.  So life is good.

BUT, Ubuntu doesn't believe this resolution exists.  Which means EVERY time I boot my computer, the login screen changes the resolution back to 3840x2160 (you can watch it change back).  Then once I log in, I have to launch the nVidia settings tool and change it back.  EVERY BOOT.  And, just to make this more frustrating, recently (about the time I updated to 16.04, but I'm not entirely sure that's causal.  It may be a coincidence of timing) the right edge of the menu bar seems to remain off the right edge of the screen when I change the resolution.  So, somehow it's not even noticing the resolution changed.

How can I convince my computer to run at the resolution I want, without having to change settings every boot?  And if you feel a bit existential, why are the settings from a tool designed to set settings being ignored?